# How to grab certain nodes in this situation onClick in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a basic food app, where  when a user clicks a menuItem div, I can pass the parent's child  food item's name and price to a useState object called clickFood. What is the best practice to grab the div's child nodes that contain the name and price in React? I've mess around a bit with useRef,but no luck and I tried some other Dom related stuff, but I feel like I was going starting to go against React and do direct Dom manipulation, which isnt best practice. Thanks for any help.

```
const recipes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Bánh mì",
    ingredients: [
      "Pork belly, fish cakes, meatballs, and the very necessary pickled carrots, on a French Baguette",
    ],
    price: "$7.50",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Phở",
    ingredients: [
      "Assortment of meat, bean sprouts, lime wedges, basil, mint, cilantro, onions,chili sauce, & fish sauce ",
    ],
    price: "$7.50",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Bún chả",
    ingredients: [
      "Grilled pork sausage patties, a basket of herbs, bean sprouts, pickled veggies, and, once again, the ever-important nước chấm sauce",
    ],
    price: "$7.50 ",
  },
];

function Order() {
  const [food, setFood] = useState(recipes);
  const [clickFood, setClickFood] = useState([item, price]);
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState();

  function itemClick(e) {
    console.log("click");
    //Here I want to setClickFood the div's price and food item name.
  }

  return (
    <div className="Menu">
      <div></div>
      <h1 style={{ color: "red", position: "relative", right: "20vw" }}>
        Main Dishes
      </h1>

      <section className="appMenu">
        <h5 className="menugrid">
          {" "}
          {food.map((meal) => (
            <div className="menuItem" onClick={itemClick}>
              <h3 className="name" style={{ color: "red" }} key={meal.id}>
                {meal.name}
              </h3>
              <h4 key={meal.ingredients}>{meal.ingredients}</h4>
              <h4 key={meal.price}>{meal.price}</h4>
            </div>
          ))}
        </h5>

        <section className="appOrder">
          <div className="orderContainer">
            <h1> Your Order</h1>
          </div>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass food items in the itemlick function and in the function you can do what you want to calculate from 1 item.

Here is the example

```
 <div className="menuItem" onClick={() => itemClick(meal)}>

 function itemClick(item) {
console.log("click");
//Here You can access 1 item on which you will click and can do what you want with values
```

}